# SLOT for statusbar->messageChanged() QT

Tags: c++, qt, statusbar, uistatusbar, qstatusbar

I've problem with QT statusbar. I want to recive and process changeMessage from statusbar, bo I have problem with slot. How I should write correct slot or how to use connect function correct, with which I've problem too.

file.cpp

```
connect(statusbar, SIGNAL(messageChanged(const QString &message)), this, SLOT(func1(const QString &message)));
```

and on the bottom

```
void file::func1(const QString &message)
{
    statusBarElements->at(0)->setText(statusBarTextElements->at(0));
}
```

file.h

```
private slots:

void func1(const QString &message);
```

And I've recived the message

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for func1(QString)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and show any error message(s) as text verbatim.

Comment: in file.h `private slots: void func1(const QString &message);`, and in file.cpp line as above. After running code I've recived `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for func1(QString)`

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68377742/edit) facility to add the code to your question.

Comment: what is statusbar object type?

Comment: statusbar is default QStatusBar

Comment: Remove the argument name `message` from the text in the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros.  Better still, use the new [signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#New:_connecting_to_QObject_member).

Comment: @G.M. if I well understand, I should have: `connect(statusbar, messageChanged, this, func1);` ?
After change like that I've recived:
`reference to non-static member function must be called` and
`use of undeclared identifier 'messageChanged'`

Comment: Please see the answer by @Mestkon .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Qt5` you don't need the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros in the connect.

```
connect(statusbar, &QStatusBar::messageChanged, this, &file::func1);
```

This will fail at compile time and give you an error message if the signatures are incompatible.

Edit:
As @G.M. stated in the comments
`QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for func1(QString)` is an error Qt gives when one tries to use a slot as a signal.

Comment: With that I come back to the begining and recive: `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for func1(QString)` durring running of the program

Comment: @Miziol Sorry, but I don't believe that error message comes from the code you've shown.  It suggests you're trying to use `func1` as a `signal` rather than a `slot`.

Comment: When I move `connect` over `ui->setupUI(this);` it start work, but program stop with ERROR when step into connect function

Comment: @Miziol That is because the statusbar UI element does not exist before you setup the UI.

Comment: @Mestkon, but now I have this order: `ui->setupUI();`, `statusbar = statusBar();` and at the end `connect(statusbar, &QStatusBar::messageChanged, this, &file::func1)`, should I change this?

Comment: Ok. well, error was in func1, where I make mistake and don't change pointer to value. But still I don't understand why Compiler and Debuger return mi error in `connect` function.

Comment: The only reason why you would get an error message saying `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for func1(QString)` is because somewhere in your program you are `connect`ing using a slot where `connect` expects a signal.